# Object Reset method or new reference for event subscribers?

Tags: c#, events, default-value

(Using VS2010.  Assume performance is not an issue).

I have a particular object that implements events for all its property changes.  Sometimes it will be necessary to "reset" the object to all its default property values.  The easiest way to do this is simply construct a new object:

`Object1= New MyObject`

However, for any event subscribers to the original object, this is equivalent to a change of all property values.  For example, if a subscriber was listening only for updates to property `A`, now it must also be aware of the possibility of new object construction.  This seems to add extra effort for subscribers.  (For example, maybe I would have to create a "NewObjectAssigned" event, and subscribers to property changes would need to handle that as well.)

So instead I was thinking of outfitting the object with a Reset method, so the above code changes to:

`Object1.Reset`

That way the Object1 reference never changes, and the `Reset` would manually change all properties to default values, thereby triggering all propertychanged events.  But this also doesn't feel quite right, and cumbersome compared to just declaring a new object.  I guess it irks me to need a method that either manually resets all properties or raises all changed events - I'd have to remember to update this method whenever new properties are added to the class.  Or perhaps this isn't as problematic as I'm making it out to be.

This is a simple enough scenario that I'm sure there is a best practices for this, one way or another.  Which is preferable?

Comment: You'd have to define some criteria judge what proposal is "preferable".  One option is to use a wrapper class to wrap the other class (that contains properties) and simple re-instantiate it to reset to default.  Similar to the adapter pattern, the adapter would then provide the events and pass-along access to the implementation class's properties.

Comment: So for the wrapper class, when the interior class is re-instantiated, would the wrapper then have to raise every property changed event for the sake of external subscribers?

Comment: Yes, generally what it's wrapping wouldn't raise the events, the wrapper would--so, should be same amount of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I agree with Peter Ritchie's first comment, that my original question was lacking in details necessary to determine a "preferable" method.  As it stands, I'm probably going with his suggestion of a wrapper class, that will be responsible for handling new object references and exposing events to subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your event handlers to stay attached, then you'll want to use a reset instead of creating a new instance. If your object implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx), then you can send a single event for the reset with [`PropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertyname.aspx) set to null.

From MSDN:

> An Empty value or null for the propertyName parameter indicates that all of the properties have changed.

Comment: Unfortunately this object does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but still good to know that empty/null propName indicates all changed - I never knew that.